# answering the phone vs taking the call

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between

**answering the phone**

and

**taking the call**

??

Are they interchangeable? or Do they have some difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Take a call* means *agree to answer* while *answer the phone* means *pick up the phone and speak when it rings*.

To make it clear, let me make an example: your friend calls your home. Your Mum *answers the phone* but you're not willing to talk to your friend so you won't *take the call*.

Answer (score 2):

to take the call = to speak with the caller

to answer the phone:  to say "hello" (or similar) when the phone is ringing

> Mr Jones, John Q. Public is on line 3.
>   --Tell him I'm not in the office. I don't want to take his call.
>
> Ring!  Ring!
>   -- Hello.